# @Bean configuration instead of context.xml

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, spring, java-melody

i am using following config in my spring context.xml to register patterns for Java melody configuration. 
i want to move this out as a spring bean. can anyone help me with this? i am having trouble setting it up properly.

```
 <bean id="facadeMonitoringAdvisor" class="net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringSpringAdvisor">
        <property name="pointcut">
                <bean class="org.springframework.aop.support.JdkRegexpMethodPointcut">
                        <property name="patterns" value="com.abc.service.*.*(..)" />
                        <property name="excludedPatterns" value="com.abc.service.*.getEntityManager(),com.abc.service.xyz.integration.gateway.*,com.abc.service.xyz.webservice.*" />
                </bean>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "move this out as a spring bean"? The sample you pasted in fact is a spring bean configuration. Do you mean you want to configure this as `Annotation`?

Comment: yes, sorry if i was not clear. i want to move it out to a java pojo config class, where using annotation i can create the bean.

Comment: then I suppose your question is little broad, you need to start first and if you face some problem (**specific problem**) you can come back. To start with you might want to look something like this http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/

Comment: You want to write a `@Bean` method within a `@Configuration` class?

Comment: yes @ Bean in @ Configuration class. i want an equivalent of the xml form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a `@Configuration` class. For each `bean` tag in xml, create a method annotated with `@Bean`. In this case it would look something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MonitoringContext
{
    @Bean(name="facadeMonitoringAdvisor")
    public MonitoringSpringAdvisor getMonitoringSpringAdvisor() {
         MonitoringSpringAdvisor msa = new MonitoringSpringAdvisor();
         msa.setPointcut(getJdkRegexpMethodPointcut());
         return msa;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdkRegexpMethodPointcut getJdkRegexpMethodPointcut() {
         JdkRegexpMethodPointcut jrm = new JdkRegexpMethodPointcut();
         jrm.setPatterns("com.abc.service.*.*(..)");
         jrm.setExcludedPatterns("com.abc.service.*.getEntityManager(),com.abc.service.xyz.integration.gateway.*,com.abc.service.xyz.webservice.*");
         return jrm;
    }
}
```

Comment: i was also able to come up finally with the same structure. but thanks alot anyways for providing this.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Spring documentation for AOP [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-enable-aspectj-java)